# How to have three different bootstrap menu colors on one css file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two pages that the bootstrap navigation menu color is different than the rest of the pages (total three different settings).
The navigation menu is one html file (that is linked to each page).
I want to have all code on ONE css file. How would I do that please?
Thank you. Here is a sample of the code:

```
    .navbar-default {
    background-color: #65625B;
    background-color: transparent;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4c000000,endColorstr=#4c000000);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4c000000,endColorstr=#4c000000)";
    zoom: 1; 
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) !important;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-color: #65625B;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) !important;
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media(max-width:767px){
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #65625B !important;
    border-color: #65625B !important;
}
}

/* 3-bar button color */
.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: #65625B !important;
}

/* 3-bar button hover */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #83817b !important;
}

/* 3-bar button border */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #65625B !important;
}
```

Comment: different classes?

Comment: You may can add different class in to navbar in different pages using jQuery at page loading time.

Comment: Thank you Hash and ashanrupasinghe for your time and answers. I used ID's as suggested by Gerard below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each page has its own body, assign a unique ID to the page that requires a different color.

```
<body id="my-blue-navigation">
```

Then in your CSS you refer to the correct class.

```
#my-blue-navigation .navbar-default {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```css
nav {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
}

.navbar-default {
background-color: red;
}

#my-blue-navigation .navbar-default {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body id="my-blue-navigation">
<nav class="navbar-default">
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Gerard :) I had tried that before but whatever reason it didn't work - you brought the magic <3